# what is user that executes windows batch file

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, uac

I have .bat file which works with network path using directory stack and therefore needs network privileges. My PC is member of domain. And here is strange thing: when I run batch file using double click on it - it works. If I will choose "Run as diffrent user" and enter my credentials such as `DOMAIN\USER` and password - this batch file works not properly. Therefore question - under which user batch file is executed when clicked? UAC is turned off I believe.

**EDIT**

here's batch script:

```
for /r %%F in (Output_AutomatedBuild\TestsResults\Coverage\*.cover.xml) do (%
xslt2xml.exe ncover2newncover.xsl %%F %%F
)
```

here's C# source code of xslt2xml.exe program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XslTransform myXslTransform;
            myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
            myXslTransform.Load(args[0]);
            myXslTransform.Transform(args[1], args[2]);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see exception won't be thrown so exit code always be equal to zero.

Comment: It's run with the user-credentials you're typing in. But, it also highly depends on what the script is doing.

Comment: @Vanadis OP asks for the credentials used when running from double-click.

Comment: @gronostaj I'm aware of this fact. The context under which the batch-file is running, is the same as the credentials, but it's possible to run certain functions in the script as a different user, for example if he's running a 3rd-party-executable.

Comment: @Vanadis I will post script in few minutes

Comment: @seeker please remove anything personal before posting it.

Comment: @Vanadis edited my answer

Comment: @seeker Rightclick on xslt2xml.exe -> properties. Check Compatibility and Security.

Comment: well my domain account have "Full control" permission on that file

Comment: @seeker try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas on the exe.

Comment: Are you sure your problem is related to permissions and not simply paths? (i.e. try using an absolute path)